# How can I disable the texture in this code?

Tags: c++, opengl-es, textures

I am playing around with Vuforia, and it's OpenGL code, but I don't really know what everything does. I just want to disable the texture in this, as the code I generate from `.obj` files does not contain a texture file.

I simply want someone to tell me what each block does and how I can clear the texture, so my model is entirely white (or white with shadows, if that is easy to do).

```
// Clear colour and depth buffers
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

// Render video background
[appRenderer renderVideoBackground];

glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
// We must detect if background reflection is active and adjust the culling direction.
// If the reflection is active, this means the pose matrix has been reflected as well,
// therefore standard counter clockwise face culling will result in "inside out" models.
glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
glCullFace(GL_BACK);

for (int i = 0; i < state.getNumTrackableResults(); ++i) {
    // Get the trackable
    const Vuforia::TrackableResult* result = state.getTrackableResult(i);
    Vuforia::Matrix44F modelViewMatrix = Vuforia::Tool::convertPose2GLMatrix(result->getPose());

    // OpenGL 2
    Vuforia::Matrix44F modelViewProjection;

    VuforiaApplicationUtils::translatePoseMatrix(0.0f, 0.0f, kObjectScale, &modelViewMatrix.data[0]);
    VuforiaApplicationUtils::scalePoseMatrix(kObjectScale, kObjectScale, kObjectScale, &modelViewMatrix.data[0]);
    VuforiaApplicationUtils::multiplyMatrix(&projectionMatrix.data[0], &modelViewMatrix.data[0], &modelViewProjection.data[0]);

    glUseProgram(shaderProgramID);

    glVertexAttribPointer(vertexHandle, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (const GLvoid*)teapotVertices);
    glVertexAttribPointer(normalHandle, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (const GLvoid*)teapotNormals);
    glVertexAttribPointer(textureCoordHandle, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (const GLvoid*)teapotTexCoords);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(vertexHandle);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(normalHandle);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(textureCoordHandle);

    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, augmentationTexture[i].textureID);
    glUniformMatrix4fv(mvpMatrixHandle, 1, GL_FALSE, (const GLfloat*)&modelViewProjection.data[0]);
    glUniform1i(texSampler2DHandle, 0 /*GL_TEXTURE0*/);
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, NUM_TEAPOT_OBJECT_INDEX, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, (const GLvoid*)teapotIndices);

    glDisableVertexAttribArray(vertexHandle);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(normalHandle);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(textureCoordHandle);

    VuforiaApplicationUtils::checkGlError("EAGLView renderFrameVuforia");
}

glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE);
```

The `glDrawElements` call seems important, but what do I pass if I don't need the texture? Do I enable and disable the `VertexAttribArray`? What does that even do?

Comment: Which version of OpenGL are you using? Are there any shaders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way would be to edit the shader code that uses the texture to use white color. It should be similar to replacing `texture2D(texture, coord)` with `vec4(1.0)`

Alternatively you can use `glTexImage2d` to upload a white texture which can created in 1x1 buffer containing following data:

```
GLubyte texdata[1 * 1 * 4] = {0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF};
```

Comment: Yes indeed they use shaders. I'll replace the `gl_FragColor = texture2D(texSampler2D, texCoord);` that is there now with `vec4(1.0);`

Comment: So your answer is technically correct, but I now see the thing entirely in white. I want it to have a bit of shadow, so that it is obvious that it is a 3D object. Is it easy to add a light somewhere so that shadows are cast on the object, giving the 3D feel?

Comment: @vrwim You can use the alternative solution for that. Without looking into the shader code, nothing much can be said to improve former solution.